# vlc rtsp to mp4 transcoding error

Tags: vlc

I am trying to transcode a live rtsp stream to a mp4 file using cvlc but getting the error below.
Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Here's the command that I use -

```
cvlc -vvv rtsp://184.173.147.99:5555/mpeg2TransportStreamFromUDPSourceTest --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=none,vb=128,deinterlace}:file{dst=out.mp4}'
```

Here's the error that I get

```
[0x7f72400011b8] avcodec encoder debug: libavcodec already initialized
[mpeg4 @ 0x29ef5c0] timebase 333333/20000000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the timebase denominator is 65535
[0x7f72400011b8] avcodec encoder error: cannot open encoder
[0x7f72400011b8] main encoder error: Streaming / Transcoding failed
[0x7f72400011b8] main encoder error: VLC could not open the encoder.
[0x7f72400011b8] main encoder debug: no encoder module matching "any" could be loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that something is wrong with the timebase.

If you read up on this [conversation](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-April/014552.html) in the ffmpeg user list a suggestion is to define a correct framerate.

So my first guess would be to check on your command and introduce an option defining the wanted framerate as the one automatically analyzed does not fit.

Here's an updated version of your command using `--timecode-fps`:

```
cvlc -vvv rtsp://184.173.147.99:5555/mpeg2TransportStreamFromUDPSourceTest --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=none,vb=128,deinterlace}:file{dst=out.mp4}' --timecode-fps=24/1
```

Here is another updated version of your command using `--sout-transcode-fps <float>`:

```
cvlc -vvv rtsp://184.173.147.99:5555/mpeg2TransportStreamFromUDPSourceTest --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,fps=24/1,acodec=none,vb=128,deinterlace}:file{dst=out.mp4}'
```

Try different framerates e.g.: 24/1, 25/1, 30000/1001, 30/1, 30.0, 24.0, 25.0

Here is another updated version of your command with some adaptations from my side:

```
cvlc -vvv rtsp://184.173.147.99:5555/mpeg2TransportStreamFromUDPSourceTest --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=128,fps=24/1,deinterlace,acodec=none}:std{mux=mp4,dst="out.mp4",access=file}'
```

Hope this helps.